# How to display leading zero in double

Tags: objective-c, floating-point, floating-accuracy

I need to make NSNumber to display only 4 decimal points. This part of code is works, but it outputs result without leading zero.

```
double resultRoundToDecimal = [result doubleValue];
    NSNumberFormatter *resultFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [resultFormatter setRoundingMode:NSNumberFormatterRoundHalfUp];
    [resultFormatter setMaximumFractionDigits:4];
    resultData = [resultFormatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:resultRoundToDecimal]];
```

For example:
1/3 = .3333

I want:
1/3 = 0.3333

How I can to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prepend a 0 or use number formatter.

```
NSString *printStr = @"0";
printStr = [NSString stringByAppendingString: resultData];
```

Otherwise, you could use a number formatter or something similar. If your just outputting a string why not do that?

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: `resultData = "0" + resultData;` - Seriously? Do you honestly think that this will work? And even if did, that it would be a valid solution? Nah...

Comment: is resultData a string?? Can't you just prepend 0 to a string?

Comment: If you don't know stuff, don't give bad advice. No, you can't.

Comment: my bad, didn't click that it was objective C. - will fix sorry

Comment: I'm still trying to append it to my code. But I think, that it will create another problem. Your solution is to add 0 to string beginning. So I will get:

1/3 = 0.3333

4/3 = 01.3333

But i'm still not sure.

Comment: so, only append if the numeric value is greater than 1? and greater than -1? Otherwise take the number formatter route which is kind of like a sprint f

Comment: It's should work, but I think that it's a not quite rationally.

Answer (score 2):

You could choose to use string formatter too, like below

```
float val=1./3;

NSString *resultData=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.4f",val];

NSLog(@"Result = %@",resultData);
```

Comment: Very interesting idea. I have added a little fix to your code "float val=1./3;" NSLog shows exactly what I need. Now I will try to use it with variable. Thanks.

Comment: It's solved my problem, but now it always outputs variable with 4 decimal points. Result, that i need is something like: 2+2=4; 4/3=1.3333; 1/3=0.3333. Now I'm getting 2+2=4.0000; 4/3=1.3333; 1/3=0.3333.